# Has Randy Orton ever RKO'd a woman?

Tags: wwe

I've seen him RKO loads of different wrestlers, but has he ever done it to a woman?

Comment: This seems to be more of a sports question...though pro wrestling is kinda designed for TV...hmm....

Comment: Related meta discussion: [Is a question on WWE on topic?](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1449/49) The apparent consensus seems to be that story-related wrestling questions are on-topic, while sports-related ones aren't. Decide for yourself, though, to which of the two groups this question belongs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Took a bit of Googling: Stacy Keibler